# Ubuntu freezes. Which logs can I check out?

Tags: freeze, log

So my computer has lately started freezing completely when I run some programs that, in the past, would work great.

What I am unsure about however, is what logs that are available to me that could help me track down the issue after a reboot?

Thanks

Comment: First run said software in the Terminal, and see what it throws,

Answer (score 35, accepted):

check

> /var/log/syslog

If you are running gnome, then you can check the logs using "gnome-system-log" tool, type

> gnome-system-log

in the run dialog.

and check the syslog in the left hand side.

if you want to check the log using terminal,

then do,

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Check the dates of the syslog* files in /var/log, my particular hang occurred on a Friday night and had been renamed and compressed as syslog.2.gz by Monday.  Log was full of cntlm events, which to me means I once again left my browser with dozens of tabs opened.  Thus reminding me once more that one day I need to learn how to enable the out of memory killer in Ubuntu.

Comment: What do I look for in `/var/log/syslog`? Any keywords?

Comment: `gnome-system-log` opens up `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/auth.log`, and `/var/log/dpkg.log`. So, what is the difference between these 3 logs and which should we look at, and when and why?

Answer (score 16):

If the whole machine is locking up, off the top of my head, these are the likely causes:

- Overheating. You don't need logs to determine this, but fingers :)
- GPU lockup. Is it an OpenGL (3D) application, and you don't normally run those? While locked up you should be able to ssh into it from another machine.
- Thrashing. Does the hard drive light go on steadily when it locks up? Something is using too much RAM.
- Other hardware problem. Run a memtest and/or another OS...

Comment: this seams to happen to my mining rig sometimes ... so GPU lockup ... :(

Answer (score 9):

> "my computer has lately started freezing completely when I run **some
>   programs**"

What are those programs? The answer to your question is heavily depend on those **"some programs"**
Anyway, check

`/var/log/syslog`

`/var/log/kern.log` Optionally you can use `dmesg` command to view kernel messages to check if something is wrong during boot process.