# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop freezes randomly

Tags: 12.04, firefox

Every once in a while, without any warning or discernible pattern, my whole Ubuntu machine freezes; the system clock in the upper-right corner stops ticking/moving, all open applications are frozen and cannot be interacted with, the mouse cannot be moved, etc. The only fix thus far has been to restart.

The only common pattern that I *think* is a solid suspect is the fact that I believe that Mozilla Firefox (v. 20) is open and running almost every time this happens, if not every time. It happens if I leave my machine running over night (and FF is also running), and sometimes it happens while I'm actively using FF (clicking a link, doing some DOM operation, whatever).

I'd like to attack/solve this problem from both the OS- and application-perspective. I'd like to know what logs (for both Ubuntu and FF) I could start looking in for warnings, errors or failures. Also interested in what the community's input/feedback is and if there are any other suggestions for debugging. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not to make light of your issue, but getting marked as dupe is not the only potential danger here... the other is getting marked as 'too localized'.

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** http://askubuntu.com/questions/93226/ubuntu-freezes-which-logs-can-i-check-out  http://askubuntu.com/q/38367/43660  http://askubuntu.com/q/93226/43660

Answer (score 1):

I guess to read this link can help you solve your problem:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DebuggingSystemCrash