# Minecraft crashes after a few minutes, freezes computer

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, opengl

I have Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit. After playing minecraft for a few minutes, the game freezes and my whole computer stops responding. This also happens in Gmod. I tried different graphics drivers, the same thing happens. How can I stop these crashes from happening?

Comment: Check in your system log and find out what processes or applications are running or malfunctioning at the time your system starts to be unresponsive. You may be able to shorten the list of possible reasons why your system is acting up from knowing this. Post these possible processes and/or applications back in to your thread which will allow others to better assist you. good luck

Comment: how do i check system log?

Comment: This guy is having a similar issue like you are experiencing. Check out the responses as one person indicated how to check the system log and another person listed possible reasons for the system locking up. Hope this helps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/93226/ubuntu-freezes-which-logs-can-i-check-out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, sort of. I looked at system monitor and a terminal while I played, and at crash, java was reporting that it ran out of memory. The ram had also just filled up when this happened. I solved it by adding Swap space, which I did not have before. After that the game has not crashed, and looking at system monitor, when ram fills, swap is used. Hope this helps someone.