# Screen went blank (black)

Tags: 14.04, screen, lts

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for 2 weeks now. I did browsing using Firefox or Chrome then suddenly screen went blank. I tried to press any keys, but none worked. Thus I needed to press Power key to switch off my laptop.I have been using Dell Latitude D630.

Comment: Hi, what is your question? What should you do in these cases? Or what triggered it?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if my question was not clear. Yes, I would like to know what triggered it? And how to prevent it to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the log file in /var/log/syslog here is a detailed description of it: [Ubuntu freezes. Which logs can I check out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93226/ubuntu-freezes-which-logs-can-i-check-out)

but if it occured only once,I would not bother looking it up...