# Ubuntu Mate keeps freezing

Tags: 15.10, freeze, ubuntu-mate

My computer recently started freezing a lot. The freezing affects everything but the power button. Each time it freezes I have to restart my computer and this is really affecting my productivity. Thanks in advance. My question is how do I figure out what is causes the freezes and then fix that.

Comment: [Update] It seems to happen a lot when I'm watching videos on youtube and  other websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can see resources utilization of CPU and RAM for each process by running on a `terminal` the command :

> top

You can also check the RAM actually in use with this command :

> free -tm

If when your computer freeze you can't check which process cause the problem  with `top` you can according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93226/ubuntu-freezes-which-logs-can-i-check-out) check the log with :

In a terminal :

> tail -f /var/log/syslog

If you are running gnome, then you can check the logs using "`gnome-system-log`"

To launch a terminal according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183775/how-do-i-open-a-terminal) you can do :

- If you're running Unity: open the dash, type `terminal`, hit `Return`.
- If you're on the old style menus, Applications → Accessories →
  Terminal.
- `Control` + `Alt` + `T`.
- `Alt` + `F2`, `gnome-terminal`, `Return`.

After that you just had to type the command and hit enter.

When you run `top` there a 3 important column for you, each line in `top` represent a process .

1. At the **middle** you can see behind the **%CPU** the % of CPU in use for a process.
2. At the **right** of the %CPU you have **%MEM** which represent the ram.
3. And at the **just right** you have command which is the **process name** corresponding to the use of CPU and MEM .

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to sound ignorant but I am fairly new to Linux and don't really know how that info helps me.

Comment: @RiccardiDalexis No problem i will details you how to use these tools, i just see your update about watching video on Youtube, i'm 90% sure your freeze is caused by the flash player plug-in which is unmaintained on GNU/Linux .I'll edit my first answer to show you how to use top .