# Where can I find information about the last hang of the system?

Tags: freeze, log, 23.04

Sometimes, my Ubuntu 23.04 hangs forever. I still see the screen, but nothing moves and no input is detected. I can only reset the machine.

Are there any file I can inspect to understand what caused the hang?

I tried with `/var/log/syslog` but I found nothing relevant. Example:

```
2023-05-18T13:41:00.149405+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting apt-news.service - Update APT News...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.151649+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting esm-cache.service - Update the local ESM caches...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.208044+02:00 mark systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.208121+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Finished esm-cache.service - Update the local ESM caches.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.212096+02:00 mark systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.212173+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Finished apt-news.service - Update APT News.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.282053+02:00 mark NetworkManager[1205]: <info>  [1684410060.2818] manager: startup complete
2023-05-18T13:41:00.283453+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Finished NetworkManager-wait-online.service - Network Manager Wait Online.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.283698+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Reached target network-online.target - Network is Online.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.283735+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started update-notifier-download.timer - Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.283818+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started update-notifier-motd.timer - Check to see whether there is a new version of Ubuntu available.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.283856+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Reached target timers.target - Timer Units.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.325006+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started cups-browsed.service - Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.325801+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting kerneloops.service - Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.326288+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting nmbd.service - Samba NMB Daemon...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.326762+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting samba-ad-dc.service - Samba AD Daemon...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.327343+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.327362+02:00 mark systemd[1]: ubuntu-advantage.service - Ubuntu Pro Background Auto Attach was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.327985+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started whoopsie.service - crash report submission.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.330867+02:00 mark systemd[1]: kerneloops.service: Found left-over process 2901 (kerneloops) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.330893+02:00 mark systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.333616+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started kerneloops.service - Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.341685+02:00 mark systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: Can't open PID file /run/teamviewerd.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
2023-05-18T13:41:00.344816+02:00 mark whoopsie[2900]: [13:41:00] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
2023-05-18T13:41:00.345925+02:00 mark systemd[1]: whoopsie.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.347234+02:00 mark systemd-resolved[1064]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 192.168.2.1.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.360859+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started teamviewerd.service - TeamViewer remote control daemon.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.361183+02:00 mark systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.361281+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in samba-ad-dc.service - Samba AD Daemon being skipped.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.375520+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started nmbd.service - Samba NMB Daemon.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.376277+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon...
2023-05-18T13:41:00.416972+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started smbd.service - Samba SMB Daemon.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.584963+02:00 mark PackageKit: refresh-cache transaction /141_aaecedda from uid 1000 finished with success after 592ms
2023-05-18T13:41:00.630954+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Builder.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631014+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Calculator.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631042+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.clocks.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631068+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Dictionary.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631093+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Documents.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631116+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Evince/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631148+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631172+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Maps.desktop/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631195+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: adding wildcard app */*/*/org.gnome.Weather/* to plugin cache
2023-05-18T13:41:00.631216+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
2023-05-18T13:41:00.962811+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: Tried to set invalid release date: 2022
2023-05-18T13:41:01.059811+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: Tried to set invalid release date: 2022
2023-05-18T13:41:01.158088+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: unhandled property 'Sender'
2023-05-18T13:41:01.292760+02:00 mark snapd[1161]: storehelpers.go:769: cannot refresh: snap has no updates available: "bare", "blender", "code", "core22", "cups", "firefox", "gnome-42-2204", "gtk-common-themes", "kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration"
2023-05-18T13:41:01.596950+02:00 mark PackageKit: resolve transaction /142_eebbaaad from uid 1000 finished with success after 437ms
2023-05-18T13:41:01.610167+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: unhandled property 'Sender'
2023-05-18T13:41:01.712895+02:00 mark PackageKit: get-details transaction /143_abbdcead from uid 1000 finished with success after 101ms
2023-05-18T13:41:01.917000+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started snap.firefox.firefox.ebd1a0c3-7be9-4e0d-9546-4bb1fe5097d8.scope.
2023-05-18T13:41:01.920814+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.917627] kauditd_printk_skb: 9 callbacks suppressed
2023-05-18T13:41:01.920823+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.917629] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410061.913:103): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19122/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3243 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
2023-05-18T13:41:01.920824+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.917634] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410061.913:104): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/snap/snapd/19122/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3243 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
2023-05-18T13:41:01.947405+02:00 mark systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_8dL2Sf.mount: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:01.979546+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3268]: update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gimp/2.0/help /usr/share/gimp/2.0/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
2023-05-18T13:41:01.979581+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3268]: update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gtk-doc /usr/share/gtk-doc none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
2023-05-18T13:41:01.979641+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3268]: update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/libreoffice/help /usr/share/libreoffice/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
2023-05-18T13:41:01.979658+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3268]: update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
2023-05-18T13:41:01.980799+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.977677] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410061.973:105): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=3268 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:01.980807+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.977721] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410061.973:106): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=3268 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:01.980808+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.977844] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410061.973:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=3268 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:01.980810+02:00 mark kernel: [   12.977872] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410061.973:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/var/lib/" pid=3268 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:02.116809+02:00 mark kernel: [   13.111871] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410062.109:109): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=3344 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:02.116818+02:00 mark kernel: [   13.111949] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410062.109:110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3344 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:02.116819+02:00 mark kernel: [   13.111976] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410062.109:111): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3344 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:02.116820+02:00 mark kernel: [   13.112030] audit: type=1400 audit(1684410062.109:112): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=3344 comm="firefox" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2023-05-18T13:41:02.727809+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:02.739900+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.]
2023-05-18T13:41:02.741079+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Successfully made thread 3470 of process 3243 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
2023-05-18T13:41:02.741096+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:03.003316+02:00 mark dbus-daemon[1400]: [session uid=1000 pid=1400] Activating service name='io.snapcraft.Settings' requested by ':1.99' (uid=1000 pid=3492 comm="dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=i" label="snap.firefox.firefox (enforce)")
2023-05-18T13:41:03.018041+02:00 mark dbus-daemon[1400]: [session uid=1000 pid=1400] Successfully activated service 'io.snapcraft.Settings'
2023-05-18T13:41:03.018293+02:00 mark io.snapcraft.Settings[3495]: userd.go:93: Starting snap userd
2023-05-18T13:41:03.122951+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:03.123061+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:03.174097+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3637]: *** You are running in background task mode. ***
2023-05-18T13:41:03.174162+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3637]: *** You are running in headless mode.
2023-05-18T13:41:03.193612+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3637]: console.error: "/home/mark/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/7y5bbvax.default-release/storage" "to-be-removed" 0 "" "Quota"
2023-05-18T13:41:03.213944+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3243]: [ERROR glean_core] Error setting metrics feature config: Json(Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0))
2023-05-18T13:41:03.734522+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:03.743965+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.]
2023-05-18T13:41:04.194217+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3637]: console.error: "Cache folder attempt no 1"
2023-05-18T13:41:04.194274+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3637]: console.error: "couldn't find cache folder /home/mark/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/7y5bbvax.default-release/storage/to-be-removed"
2023-05-18T13:41:04.194417+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3637]: console.error: "Pinged glean, waiting for submission."
2023-05-18T13:41:04.874818+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3451]: [Child 3451, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:41:04.874880+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3451]: [Child 3451, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686664+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686706+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686733+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686749+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686766+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686783+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686807+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686821+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.686836+02:00 mark gnome-shell[1924]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
2023-05-18T13:41:05.914459+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:05.914517+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:09.050589+02:00 mark systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:13.778781+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:13.778857+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:14.001579+02:00 mark dbus-daemon[1400]: [session uid=1000 pid=1400] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract' unit='tracker-extract-3.service' requested by ':1.89' (uid=1000 pid=2467 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3" label="unconfined")
2023-05-18T13:41:14.041095+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Starting tracker-extract-3.service - Tracker metadata extractor...
2023-05-18T13:41:14.072706+02:00 mark dbus-daemon[1400]: [session uid=1000 pid=1400] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Extract'
2023-05-18T13:41:14.072840+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started tracker-extract-3.service - Tracker metadata extractor.
2023-05-18T13:41:14.254979+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3751]: [Child 3751, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:41:14.255105+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3751]: message repeated 6 times: [ [Child 3751, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:41:15.028713+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 706 (plymouthd).
2023-05-18T13:41:15.028951+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Finished plymouth-quit-wait.service - Hold until boot process finishes up.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.029344+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Reached target multi-user.target - Multi-User System.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.029380+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Reached target graphical.target - Graphical Interface.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.061454+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting setvtrgb.service - Set console scheme...
2023-05-18T13:41:15.062477+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Starting systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service - Record Runlevel Change in UTMP...
2023-05-18T13:41:15.062859+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Finished setvtrgb.service - Set console scheme.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.063330+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice - Slice /system/getty.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.066056+02:00 mark systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.066120+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Finished systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service - Record Runlevel Change in UTMP.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.066526+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Startup finished in 14.795s (firmware) + 11.314s (loader) + 3.713s (kernel) + 22.351s (userspace) = 52.174s.
2023-05-18T13:41:15.641335+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3751]: [Child 3751, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:41:15.934678+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3751]: message repeated 44 times: [ [Child 3751, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:41:16.957296+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:16.957398+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:41:23.989052+02:00 mark snapd-desktop-i[2120]: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature
2023-05-18T13:41:24.008262+02:00 mark appimagelauncherd[1379]: Directories to watch disappeared, unintegrating AppImages formerly found in there
2023-05-18T13:41:24.289377+02:00 mark systemd-timesyncd[1065]: Contacted time server 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
2023-05-18T13:41:24.289491+02:00 mark systemd-timesyncd[1065]: Initial clock synchronization to Thu 2023-05-18 13:41:23.957204 CEST.
2023-05-18T13:41:24.993067+02:00 mark snap-store[2351]: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature
2023-05-18T13:41:25.561947+02:00 mark systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:28.378365+02:00 mark systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:28.399652+02:00 mark systemd[1]: systemd-localed.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:28.870681+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3748]: [Child 3748, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:41:28.870896+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3748]: message repeated 8 times: [ [Child 3748, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:41:39.952517+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3755]: [Child 3755, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:41:39.953135+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3755]: message repeated 10 times: [ [Child 3755, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:41:45.059764+02:00 mark systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:58.032509+02:00 mark geoclue[1998]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
2023-05-18T13:41:58.034125+02:00 mark systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-18T13:41:59.029064+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dadvantage\x2dnotification-4115.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
2023-05-18T13:41:59.029247+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started app-gnome-update\x2dnotifier-4118.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
```

Here a freeze happened and I restarted the machine:

```
2023-05-18T13:43:15.339303+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3748]: [Child 3748, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:43:15.342762+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3748]: message repeated 53 times: [ [Child 3748, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:43:44.033038+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.Terminal-4171.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
2023-05-18T13:43:44.055836+02:00 mark dbus-daemon[1400]: [session uid=1000 pid=1400] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.107' (uid=1000 pid=4173 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real" label="unconfined")
2023-05-18T13:43:44.056450+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Created slice app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice - Slice /app/org.gnome.Terminal.
2023-05-18T13:43:44.056908+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Starting gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server...
2023-05-18T13:43:44.113116+02:00 mark dbus-daemon[1400]: [session uid=1000 pid=1400] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
2023-05-18T13:43:44.113171+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started gnome-terminal-server.service - GNOME Terminal Server.
2023-05-18T13:43:44.225248+02:00 mark systemd[1372]: Started vte-spawn-d27f3691-7724-4e55-a4be-b355fd796c42.scope - VTE child process 4201 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 4177.
2023-05-18T13:43:52.907660+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:43:52.907805+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:43:53.358631+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3887]: [Child 3887, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:43:54.890947+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3887]: message repeated 15 times: [ [Child 3887, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:43:54.987783+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:43:54.987850+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
2023-05-18T13:43:55.081824+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3887]: [Child 3887, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:43:55.085301+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3887]: message repeated 35 times: [ [Child 3887, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:43:55.095639+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3974]: [Child 3974, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
2023-05-18T13:43:55.096121+02:00 mark firefox_firefox.desktop[3974]: message repeated 8 times: [ [Child 3974, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57]
2023-05-18T13:43:56.108878+02:00 mark rtkit-daemon[1402]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
```

I can see this:

```
2023-05-18T13:41:00.327985+02:00 mark systemd[1]: Started whoopsie.service - crash report submission.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.330867+02:00 mark systemd[1]: kerneloops.service: Found left-over process 2901 (kerneloops) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
2023-05-18T13:41:00.330893+02:00 mark systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
```

Are those messages relevant? What should I do now?

I also have a dual boot with Windows. Until now I haven't experienced such a freeze in Windows yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu freezes. Which logs can I check out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93226/ubuntu-freezes-which-logs-can-i-check-out) You may need to install `gnome-system-log` which you will do with the command `sudo apt install gnome-system-log"

Comment: @graham no, it doesn't. It's just a tool to show logs. But I've already written I'm able to look at, say, `/var/log/syslog`. I don't need a tool, I'm just asking witch logs I need to check.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate.

Comment: journalctl and dmesg are the main other ones, and also check the file ~/.xsession-errors  if you are using cinnammon